# Ploting Stem plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime

df = web.DataReader('tip', 'yahoo', start= '1,1,2017', end = datetime.datetime.today())
df1 = df.resample('W-Mon').mean()
df1["Adj Close"].pct_change().plot()
```

This produces this plot:

[image]

To plot in stem in pandas:

```
df1["Adj Close"].pct_change().stem()
```

Is producing this error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stem'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.stem(df1["Adj Close"].pct_change().index,
        df1["Adj Close"].pct_change())
plt.show()
```

Then customise axis/title as you like.

[image]

Comment: Could I please trouble you for a follow up. Kind please advise how can i get the dates on the x axis? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the index of the pandas series to the "x" argument of plt.stem, and then we pass the values into the "y" argument. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html